# Focus first item in material menu WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListView (menu) in XAML. I'm using materialdesinginxaml.

```
<ListView x:Name="Menu" Foreground="Blue" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="Change">
    <ListViewItem x:Name="ItemSettings" Height="60">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Table" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="15 10"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Settings" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
    ...
```

How can I focus first item of this list view? SelectedIndex="0" on ListView element doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `IsSelected` property of the `ListViewItem` to `true` and focus it in the event handler:

```
private void Change(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = Menu?.SelectedItem as ListViewItem;
    if (lvi != null)
        lvi.Focus();
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListViewItem x:Name="ItemSettings" Height="60" IsSelected="True">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Table" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="15 10"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Settings" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ListViewItem>
```